# Trigger.io Facebook integration "unexpected read permissions" on some iOS devices

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, trigger.io

On an iOS 6 iPad the Facebook modal permissions dialog pops up, but when accepted it appears to do nothing.

The following error appears in our logs:

```
Jan 16 11:57:50 CloudPad Forge[21287] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Native call: {
        callid = "2CB2131C-771C-466D-9640-D1FF99AB3E4B";
        method = "facebook.authorize";
        params =     {
            dialog = 1;
            permissions =         (
                "user_photos",
                "publish_stream",
                email
            );
        };
    }
Jan 16 11:57:50 CloudPad Forge[21287] <Warning>: FBConditionalLog: FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage permissions contains unexpected read permissions

Jan 16 11:57:53 CloudPad Forge[21582] <Warning>: [DEBUG] Returning to javascript: {
        callid = "EE3606FC-84D6-4F3F-8BC6-82FAF3BEC5EF";
        content =     {
            message = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)";
            subtype = "<null>";
            type = "UNEXPECTED_FAILURE";
        };
        status = error;     }
```

The same app works fine with Facebook auth on different devices, some iOS 6, some others.

Halp!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're requesting read (`user_photos` and `email`) and write (`publish_stream`) permissions in the same call - this is not supported in the iOS SDK, see here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

> Note, to use iOS 6 native auth, apps need change the way they request permissions from users - apps must separate their requests for
>   read and write permissions. The Facebook SDK for iOS supports these
>   features and helps developers use them to build apps that work on
>   multiple iOS versions and device configurations.

Comment: The strange thing is that the same code works on another iOS 6 device. Is there a particular version of the Official FB App that I should look into? Does it matter if the device has the Official FB App installed?

Comment: It works on a different device for the same user? and both devices are/aren't logged into Facebook via the iOS6 integration?
The docs are fairly explicit about not requesting read and write permissions together if you're using the iOS6 integration, and the regular non-iOS6 auth dialog now enforces read and write permissions on separate pages of the auth dialog, so it's something you'll need to consider regardless of how your users log in

Comment: @Igy Hi! So how do I go about requesting both of those permissions? I can do so from a web app, not from my iOS.